# Clipping timeseries data to nearest hour or the nearest day

Tags: python-3.x, time-series, reshape

I have a set of 5 time series dataframes with resolution of 15mins but they do not end on the same date and time. However, the starting date and time are same. So, I would prefer to clip them so that they are of the same length.

And, then I would like to reshape the data to see weekly pattern or 14-days pattern.

The data looks like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you mean by clipping is to resample the dates and take the last value. (*correct me if I'm wrong*)

To resample you can use `.resample()` method from pandas (set your **timestamp column as index** before using this method), followed by a `.last()` to take the last value.

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> import numpy as np
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({
...     'Timestamp':pd.date_range('2021-06-21 23:07', periods = 200, freq='15min'),
...     'Speed':range(200)
>>> })
>>> print(df)
              Timestamp  Speed
0   2021-06-21 23:07:00      0
1   2021-06-21 23:22:00      1
2   2021-06-21 23:37:00      2
3   2021-06-21 23:52:00      3
4   2021-06-22 00:07:00      4
..                  ...    ...
195 2021-06-23 23:52:00    195
196 2021-06-24 00:07:00    196
197 2021-06-24 00:22:00    197
198 2021-06-24 00:37:00    198
199 2021-06-24 00:52:00    199

[200 rows x 2 columns]
>>> df_grouped = df.set_index('Timestamp').resample('1H').last()
>>> print(df_grouped.head(10))
                     Speed
Timestamp                 
2021-06-21 23:00:00      3
2021-06-22 00:00:00      7
2021-06-22 01:00:00     11
2021-06-22 02:00:00     15
2021-06-22 03:00:00     19
2021-06-22 04:00:00     23
2021-06-22 05:00:00     27
2021-06-22 06:00:00     31
2021-06-22 07:00:00     35
2021-06-22 08:00:00     39
```

Comment: Great! Somehow I missed the .last(). Thanks, again